# How do I control which element is "selected" by default when the WPF application starts - i.e., where the keyboard cursor is by default on startup?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

Specifically, I want to be able to launch my WPF (C#) application and then immediately be able to switch between two radio buttons using the arrow keys.

As it is, I need to use the Tab key or the mouse to "select" one of the radio buttons, and *then* I can start hopping between them using arrow keys.

*Important note*: I am *not* asking how to control which radio button is *checked* by default. I'm asking how to how to optimize keyboard user-friendliness of my WPF controls.

Comment: Try FocusManager.

Comment: _Focus_ was indeed the magical word to search for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Focus () function to choose the item selected when the window opens.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Button1.Focus();
        }
```

And you can define TabIndex orders to optimize the user experience.

In Xaml :

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" TabIndex="0"/>
<Button x:Name="Button2" TabIndex="1"/>
<Button x:Name="Button3" TabIndex="2"/>
```

Or in C# :

```
Button1.TabIndex = 0;
Button2.TabIndex = 1;
Button3.TabIndex = 2;
```